# What would be the consequences of deleting a recovery partition

Tags: windows, partitioning

I recently upgraded my 64 bit HP laptop's OS from windows 8.1 to windows 10 via the official free online upgrade offered.  This resulted in a recovery partition being created (actually a second one - the OEM one was already present)

What would be the consequences if I deleted the same?

I have made win 10 recovery disk

Thanks

Comment: So you have recovery partitions for 8.1 and 10?  Which one don't you want to be able to recover?

Answer (score 3):

The Windows 10 recovery partition you have is for the WinRE system, used when Windows is in a completely unbootable state (You may have seen this booting previously as 'Startup repair':

[image: Startup Repair]

The Windows 10 upgrade includes this recovery option, and whilst not essential, it is required if you ever want to use the startup repair option.

Bear in mind, this is usually very small, and worth keeping in case of emergency as it can be useful enough to get you back to a booting system. Recovering the space is not as simple as just removing it, you'll need to also extend the current system partition, which, if the recovery partition is *before* it, will need to be done with third party software. Honestly, the amount of space recovered and the risks involved with removing it, I would leave it as it is, but the machine will still boot and function without it.

Further information on this partition [here](http://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/recovery-partition-after-upgrading-to-windows-10-4348.html)

**Edit: My post below here was misinterpreting that you wished to delete the OEM recovery partition. I have left it just in case.**

You won't be able to use the recovery option bundled with the machine (usually a key press on boot). It shouldn't affect the ability to use a disc to recover, but this could vary by manufacturer.

Unless you're confident with installing a completely clean Windows installation if things go horribly wrong, it would be advisable to leave alone (they usually don't really take a huge amount of space, normally the equivalent of a usb stick).

If you're happy to do a clean install if needed, then it's entirely up to you. Bear in mind, simply removing it won't make that space usable immediately, you'd need to put another formatted partition in it's place, or extend your main partition into it, which may not be straight forward as the space is usually before your system partition.

Comment: Thanks Jonno: What is I have made a recovery disk from the control panel options and covered myself - can I now safety delete my recovery partitions?

Comment: How large is the partition? As said, you can if you've made alternative media, sure, but if the disc gets damaged or lost, it would be more of a headache to get your machine up and running. Personally, I leave them intact just to be sure. I'd recommend booting from your DVD before removing anything either way, just to be sure it is at least functional in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

The consequences are: You will need a Windows installation medium, if you want to use the recovery feature in the future.

You can execute the following command in an elevated command prompt:

```
reagentc /info
```

to gather information about your current recovery environment. It will especially show you on which partition on which harddisk your current recovery partition is located.

You can then safely remove the other partition.

If you also want to remove the active recovery partition, disable your recovery environment from an elevated command prompt first:

```
reagentc /disable
```

and remove the partition afterwards. This is better than just deleting the active recovery partition, as there won't be any pointers to the deleted partition anymore and your OS will be aware that you don't want a recovery partition.