# Deleting Recovery Partition - What will happen?

Tags: partitioning, windows-8.1, backup, partition-recovery, recovery

I need to free up as much space as possible on my hdd. I have the following partitions seen below:

[disk management pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yrdp.jpg)
The 5th partition in particular is called:
13.96 GB
Healthy (Recovery Partition).

What are the consequences of deleting this partition and combining it into C? 
Does it just mean I can't restore to factory settings? Or will it destroy my ability to backup the system using an externally stored system image?
I don't have any boot disks or anything for this laptop, its a lenovo ideapad 510p.
I have multiple backups made with lenovo's One Key Recovery (OKR). I don't know if I will lose functionality or not with OKR or my ability to use my backups. OKR was on my D drive but I moved it to my C drive and combined D to C for space, so maybe I'm good and everything is separate?

Again I am not concerned about losing the ability to factory reset, I have many backups on external drives, particularly one of it right when I got it.

Comment: It appears I was mistaken about the One Key Recovery being something you can download. [How to recover preloaded Windows if the hidden partition was damaged or formatted](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht104185).  **If you want to use One Key Recovery don't delete the partition you are asking about.**  Since you no longer have a Lenovo partition you won't be able to reinstall it.  [Accidentally uninstall OneKey Recovery from preload Windows 10, how to get it back](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht500798)

Comment: I do have a lenovo partition right here on my drive. One key recovery works fine on my system. The contents of the recovery partitions stating they are empty is a trick, they are hidden from windows explorer. If you use command prompt u can see they are there taking up space. if windows explorer could see them u might accidently delete them

Comment: If you can see them then copy the One Key Recovery installer files and delete the partition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would be the consequences of deleting a recovery partition](https://superuser.com/questions/1023849/what-would-be-the-consequences-of-deleting-a-recovery-partition)